# Count number of logins per day in PHP Timeclock (PHP Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

What are the mysql codes to **count the number of logins per day** in PHP Timeclock?

timestamp bigint(14) is used and I have no idea how to separate them by date.

How do I count the number of ROWS per day?

Here's the command to create the table info:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  fullname varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `inout` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  timestamp bigint(14) default NULL,
  KEY fullname (fullname)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Sorry I'm just a newbie trying to understand php and MySQL.

Anyway, I can add either of the two in info table:
       timestamp timestamp default NULL,
or     logindate date default NULL,

Suppose I have this portion of the code saved in a php file, how can I modify it so date or timestamp is inserted in info table everytime a user logs in?

```
$time = time();
$hour = gmdate('H',$time);
$min = gmdate('i',$time);
$sec = gmdate('s',$time);
$month = gmdate('m',$time);
$day = gmdate('d',$time);
$year = gmdate('Y',$time);
$tz_stamp = mktime ($hour, $min, $sec, $month, $day, $year);

    if (strtolower($ip_logging) == "yes") {
        $query = "insert into ".$db_prefix."info (fullname, `inout`, timestamp, notes, ipaddress) values ('".$fullname."', '".$inout."', 
                  '".$tz_stamp."', '".$notes."', '".$connecting_ip."')";
    } else {
        $query = "insert into ".$db_prefix."info (fullname, `inout`, timestamp, notes) values ('".$fullname."', '".$inout."', '".$tz_stamp."', 
                  '".$notes."')";
    }

    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: As a side note, you might want to use an INT as a key (`id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`) because searches in the future will be a lot faster that way, plus `fullname` might change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a BIGINT (why, btw?) I assume it's a UNIX Timestamp. 
I haven't tested this, but something along the lines of this should work:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) AS date, COUNT(*)
FROM info
GROUP BY date
```

You might wanna just store the timestamp as a TIMESTAMP column type, and then just use `DATE(timestamp)` to group by date.

Comment: `COUNT(id)` should be `COUNT(*)` - there is no column `id` in this table.

Comment: By the way, the codes are from PHP timeclock which is a web-based system. I'm just trying to modify it.

Comment: Well when logging in just run `UPDATE info timestamp=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE fullname="the user's name"` of course modify to your needs. Did the answer above work for you? If so please mark as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: The answer above almost worked. It's just that instead of showing the date under the timestamp column, several NULLs appear in rows.

Comment: It's now working. This command worked:

SELECT DATE( from_unixtime( timestamp ) ) AS date, COUNT( * ) 
FROM info
WHERE timestamp
BETWEEN 0 
AND 9999999999999999999999999999999 
GROUP BY DATE( from_unixtime( timestamp ) ) 
ORDER BY timestamp

Comment: Wait, why the where? You can just use `WHERE timestamp IS NOT NULL` or something

Answer (score 0):

Add a column of date only (without the time) and use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), dateColumn FROM info WHERE fullname='{The user full name}' GROUP BY dateColumn
```

Comment: Hi! I've edited my question. Can you look into the codes. I can't figure out how date can be inserted in the info table everytime a user logs in.

Comment: You need to insert new row with the current date each time the user login